# How to find least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation in Julia?

Tags: numpy, julia, least-squares

I would like to know if there is an alternate function for `numpy.linalg.lstsq()` in Julia. The function returns a least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation. the correct syntax to access elements from NumPy stack ?

Python Example:

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]
m, c
(1.0 -0.95) # may vary
```

Output Chart:

[image]

Python Reference: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/JuliaStats/GLM.jl ?

Comment: @JunTian thanks for the suggestion, will try to have a look at it !

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can just use `\` from Julia Base:

```
julia> A = [rand(10) ones(10)]
10×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.637746  1.0
 0.296172  1.0
 0.795938  1.0
 0.611058  1.0
 0.737017  1.0
 0.992014  1.0
 0.914031  1.0
 0.522682  1.0
 0.3607    1.0
 0.934141  1.0

julia> y = A * [1, -1] + rand(10) ./ 10
10-element Vector{Float64}:
 -0.34049611405598046
 -0.6368145973747783
 -0.10597203750574954
 -0.2950574213524233
 -0.19571807260629853
  0.020902316863572645
 -0.07310077005612584
 -0.40758393396440784
 -0.6137424837773662
 -0.05149257027230776

julia> A \ y
2-element Vector{Float64}:
  0.9582937347300398
 -0.9216908912065571
```

Comment: So the `\\` operator does the pseudo-inverse for overconstrained systems?

Comment: Yes, same as in Matlab. Well, it doesn't explicitly create the pseudo-inverse.

Comment: There is one corner case, for square `A`, where this approach fails if `A` is singular, e.g. `[1 1; 2 2] \ [1, 2]`, The reason is that the specification of `\` is different for square and non-square matrices.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński thanks for the suggestion, this is amazing and since it doesnot require specific packages, it will be faster too. 
However, I hope for my case this does not face singular case. Maybe I will give it a thorough inspection of kinds on inputs. But may i ask if there is any work around ?

Comment: yes - you can use `using LinearAlgebra; qr(A) \ y`, but it might be less efficient.

Comment: @MohammadSaad Loading and using external packages may increase compile time, but it's not necessarily slower at runtime. External packages can be as fast as built-in functionality.